# Input string was not in a correct format visual basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, format

```
    int VoltageTypeID = Int32.Parse(ddlVoltageType.SelectedValue);

    if (VoltageTypeID == 1)
    {
        lblApplicationType.Visible = false;
        lbldoubledot4.Visible = false;
        ddlApplicationType.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        lblApplicationType.Visible = true;
        lbldoubledot4.Visible = true;
        ddlApplicationType.Visible = true;
    }
```

`int VoltageTypeID = Int32.Parse(ddlVoltageType.SelectedValue)` (this is the format error)

Comment: `ddlVoltageType.SelectedValue` is not numeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your ddlVoltageType.SelectedValue while running by using debugging mode.
ddlVoltageType.SelectedValue maybe have your first value like a "Select This" .
That string cannot convert to Integer thats why its throwing "Input string was not in a correct format " error.

Comment: Ah, so shall i remove the "select this" code or there is another code to ignore that?